# XSLT - validations

Tags: validation, xslt, exslt

I have a ESB ( Data-power) based service, which fetches individual details from back end. When the response comes back to ESB in the form of SOAP message, we do some validations on the response. After validations, response is send back to front end with validation results. there are no buisness faults here.  I have following questions on this -

1. There are multiple individual records returned by the back-end. I need to do the same validations on all the records. how can i achieve this iterative functionality in XSLT or EXSLT?
2. How can i check a response field ( string) against a list of string values. Like if A is equal to B or C or D do this or do that.
3. Is there any tool to generate the validation XSLT directly from the response XSD?

Plz help, its a production setting and its pretty urgent. i dont have any background whatsoever in XSLT.

Comment: I'm confused by question (3). Why would you want to do the validation using an XSLT processor rather than an XSD schema validator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may do this validation using XSLT.
Try [Oxigen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/).

And yes using XSLT 2 you may write pretty complex validation rules.